# Many-to-many relationship in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In a scenario where we have a many-to-many relationship, what would be the ideal thing to implement an endpoint where you can get the data registered specifically for user X? For example, a class having multiple teachers and a teacher having multiple classes.

I'm using typeorm to make the relations. But on the front end, I have a screen that I need to get all the classes.

That's why I thought of putting the array of classes in the teachers table, because if I implement only the endpoint to get all the classes, I will actually get all the classes, instead of just the classes registered for the user. Or do relationships already solve this problem?

In addition to the specific classes for each teacher, I need to get some data that is in the class. Like name, number of students, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, the best solution would be to put an array of classes in your teacher table. Then they could consume this endpoint to consume the class data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need a intermediated table, witch will have the Id of the Teacher (Primary Key of the Teachers table) and the Id of the Class (Primary Key of the Class table).

This way you can know witch or how many class the teacher (ID) have and the same for direction, how many teachers have the class (ID) by query to this table

*Example*:
Table Teacher:

| **Id** | **Name** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary |

Table Class

| **Id** | **Name** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 2 | Geo |

Table TeachersClass

| **Id** | **TeacherId** | **ClassId** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

To know the teacher Mary class:

```
$ Select * From TeachersClass Where TeacherId = 1
```

And at the end, with the Class Id you get all information you need from the class table.

Comment: Hi Jandrade. I understand, create an intermediate table with the id of the class and the id of the teacher. But in addition to knowing the classes that the teacher has, I need to consult the data of this class and render it on a screen. For example, number of students, shifts, etc. And on this screen, only the classes registered for teacher id can appear. If I create a route to this intermediate table, wouldn't it just show the id of that teacher's classes? How would I query other class data besides the id?

Comment: This vastly expands the issue. In addition to the tables currently involved you would also a M:M between Students:Classes and whatever/wherever shifts are.  BTW: Storing an array in a single column is virtually always the wrong approach in a RDBMS.

Comment: Agree with @Belayer - It's new question or a vastly questions you are comment

But I will try to help you - You need to create the same logic in the DB for the students and etc ... 
You need to construct a logic with code to reunite all the information from the different tables. Some frameworks (depends on the tech you are using) can do this job for you.
At the end of the day, your endpoint will respond with a JSON with all information together you need

Edit - Missing information

Comment: For example,
You run my first query to know the class the teacher 1 have. It will return you the Id the of the Class. Then, you will make a query to the Class table were Id is equal to the Id you have. In same cases you will need a loop because the teacher can have multiple Class and you have to query one by one
This way, you know all about the class the Teacher 1 have